# A custom theme with support for multiple layouts

Tags: theme-development

I've been tasked with creating a custom WP theme for my company's website. I know PHP and decent WP plugin development but haven't worked with themes before. I'm using Underscore as a base for my theme and have written styles for header, footer etc.

Now my boss wants that the theme have support for different layouts kind of like what you see in premium themes. And the users can go in theme settings then choose the layout they want. I've searched around but found nothing on this. So, my question is using Underscore how do I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding of what you need, you want to create page templates. Page templates are a specific type of template file that can be applied to a specific page or groups of pages, you can apply a custom design to different page templates as per your requirement.

You can read more about page templates here: 
- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/ 
- https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/